# How activate Discord presence rich in codespaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, discord, codespaces

Recently, I discovered CodeSpaces on GitHub, and I decided to give it a try because I change computers frequently. While setting my preferences and installing extensions, I encountered a problem.

In Vscode, I usually keep the [Discord Rich Extension activated](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LeonardSSH.vscord) to show when I'm online coding inside of editor. However, this extension was developed to work on the current machine where Discord is active. Some features connect to my Discord to show information about activity, and this no longer works on a cloud computer because Discord isn't active there.

I searched the internet for some solutions, but I didn't find anything :(

I know the reason for this is quite obvious; if it's running outside the machine, it won't be able to detect the connection, but today we have a solution for almost everything so i decide to ask here.